# Omniture - python: keyError with authentication

Tags: python, adobe-analytics

I have been trying to use the omniture module to retrieve data from omniture but I am stuck at the very first step.

I followed the instructions on the readme but when I try to authenticate I receive the following traceback:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMXNv.png)

any little help will be much appreciated !

Thanks a lot,
Bastien

Comment: This is the authenticate function from the omniture module:

Answer (score 0):

There's no `report_suites` key in the dictionary. Don't know what are you trying to find, but the best for you would be either print whole dictionary, or more efficient - print only keys and choose the one you want.

If you don't know what key do you want, printing the whole dictionary may be more useful as the values alone would be useless for you without a way to access them.

Also I think you didn't pass enough arguments to the function, because it seems that the function is missing something, therefore can't return what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your message.I just followed the guidelines from the readme file, so I am bit lost now (https://github.com/debrouwere/python-omniture/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: @Bastien Open the link `https://api.omniture.com/admin/1.3/rest/...` with proper arguments yourself and see if there's something like `report_suites` or just open `account.py` from your installed omniture package and dump `data = self.request('Company', 'GetReportSuites')` - without `['report_suites']` to a file to see what's in there. If you fail at the first step, that package is outdated most probably(it's 3y old). I think the json you would get from that call is reorganized, therefore it can't find key `'report_suites'`